# close jquery mobile dialog programatically, then returned to a blank page

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, dialog

I open/close a JQuery-mobile dialog programatically using changepage and dialog('close'), but the problem is after closing, the page initiated the dialog show is blank, nothing left. how to fix this problem

using JQuery-mobile with backbone view and router and phone gap

code

open dialog

```
//render
            __this.currentDialog.render(
                function() { //done rendering
                    $.mobile.changePage(__this.currentDialog.$el, {'role' : 'dialog', 'transition' : 'pop', 'changeHash' : false});
                }
            );
```

close dialog

```
dialogView.$el.dialog('close');
```

Comment: Dialog widget will be deprecated on JQM v 1.4. Use popups if you like.

Comment: Thanks alot, popup works much better!!